# Mean of Cell in R

Tags: r, list, split

My Initial Data looks like this:

```
ID<-c(1,2,3,4)
Value<-c("1,2","0,-1",1,"","")
Data<-data.frame(ID, Value)
```

I want to create a MeanValue from Value for every Row. And if the Value is having no Value in it, i would like to take the Mean for the Value.

My Idea to Compute the Mean for the first Step was:

```
library(stringr)
AverageMean<-mean(as.numeric(str_split(Data$Value, ",")))
```

But it is Creating an Error

The Final Data should kinda look like:

```
ID<-c(1,2,3,4)
Value<-c("1,2","0,-1",1,"","")
AverageMean<-c(1.5,-0.5,1,0.666,0.666)
FinalData<-data.frame(ID, Value, AverageMean)
```

Comment: @akrun For the second step it should become the Mean of the other posts. so it changes from NA to 0.666

Comment: I'd suggest ditching `str_split` and using `strsplit` from base R instead. Would make a huge difference if you are dealing with even a moderately sized dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the info, and working on your code, first you do `str_split` on the concerned column and the output is a `list`.  For getting the `mean` for individual list elements, you can use `lapply` with `mean`.  Then `unlist` it and replace the last value `Val[length(Val)]` with the `mean` of all other values and create a new column `AverageMean` based on the above.

```
 Val <- unlist(lapply(str_split(Data$Value, ","),
                  function(x) mean(as.numeric(x), na.rm=TRUE)))
 Val[length(Val)] <- mean(Val[-length(Val)], na.rm=TRUE)
 Data$AverageMean <- Val
  Data
  #  ID Value AverageMean
  #1  1   1,2   1.5000000
  #2  2  0,-1  -0.5000000
  #3  3     1   1.0000000
  #4  4         0.6666667
```

#### Update

If you have multiple `missing values` and want to replace that with the `mean` of the column,

```
   Data <- data.frame(ID=1:5, Value=c("1,2", "0,-1", 1, "", ""))
   Val <- unlist(lapply(str_split(Data$Value, ","),
               function(x) mean(as.numeric(x), na.rm=TRUE)))
```

The above steps are the same.  Create a logical index with `is.na` and replace all those missing values by the mean of values that are not missing  by negating the logical index `!is.na`.

```
   Val[is.na(Val)] <- mean(Val[!is.na(Val)])
   Data$AverageMean <- Val
   Data
   # ID Value AverageMean
   #1  1   1,2   1.5000000
   #2  2  0,-1  -0.5000000
   #3  3     1   1.0000000
   #4  4         0.6666667
   #5  5         0.6666667
```

Comment: Correct, but then you need to replace the NaN with the average of the last values (if I understood correctly)

Comment: @akrun I just found a problem. It is not handling well the case that it has more then one Empty Value.(I just edited the question to better show the problem)